# Encryption And Decryption Of Id

Tags: c#

I want to Encrypt and Decrypt Id coming from ViewModel, and i want this Id in Encrypted form how can i set it in property set in ViewModel.

```
public class UserDto
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfJoining { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeDocumentDto> Files { get; set; }
}
```

please guide me how can i Decrypt Code here not in Logic File
mean in Logic File
Code=obj.Id.EncodeQueryString();
i want this Encryption in VM not her, here i want it
Code=obj.Id
It will Encode it.

Comment: What is the actual goal? Typically you would be mostly concerned with encrypting data at rest. Encrypting in memory data is typically more involved since you need to be careful to zero-out any memory that has held the unencrypted data, and you would typically need to use a TPM or other API to avoid storing the keys in memory. But do you want to actually *encrypt* your data, or would encoding/hashing be sufficient?

Comment: only hashing the Id which is in integer form but i need it in Encrypted form passing to Client Side

Answer (score 0):

**YOU SHOULD NOT DO THIS.**

this violate so many **best practices** and **rules** . your Dto should **not** know anything about your logic. but
you can do it like this :

```
public class UserDto
{
    private string Encrypt(string code) => code + "x";
    private string Decrypt(string code) => code + "xxx";

    private string _code;
    public string Code
    {
        get => Decrypt(_code);
        set => _code = Encrypt(value);
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfJoining { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeDocumentDto> Files { get; set; }
}
```